# Could using punch-down blocks with long stripped ethernet cables cause signal loss or any other issue?

Tags: ethernet

I see it on the internet where people strip and untwist their wires more than 10 cm to use with punch-down blocks. Won't this cause cross-talk or can other noises effect the signal when cables are stripped very long?  Isn't that bad for the signal?

Comment: Yes, removal of twist must be minimized. And "punch blocks" (66/110?) are something one should never use for ethernet. (if you're talking about the similar type of interface on a patch panel, or keystone, I wouldn't call them a punch block, even 'tho they're similar to a 110 and use the same style tool.)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also, shielded cable must be grounded on each side.